# How do I write a Python test that checks that my code imports a module

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a Python project that relies on a particular module, `receivers.py`, being imported.

I want to write a test to make sure it is imported, but I also want to write other tests for the behaviour of the code within the module.

The trouble is, that if I have any tests anywhere in my test suite that import or patch anything from `receivers.py` then it will automatically import the module, potentially making the test for import pass wrongly.

Any ideas?

(Note: specifically this is a Django project.)

Comment: That doesn't sound like a useful test at all; surely an `ImportError` would be thrown if the module is not available. Are you saying the import is conditional?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is that there is a functional requirement for receivers to be imported in the normal operating of the web framework.  This is the kind of thing that does get missed / is prone to regressions.  My issue is that the very act of testing the receivers means that they get imported during tests, even if it's been missed in the main codebase.

Comment: So you want an *integration test*, one that exercises the code that uses the receivers.

Comment: Yes I guess it is an integration test.  Trouble is, if I want to do any unit testing of the code in the receivers module, it causes the integration test to succeed, when it would fail in real life.

Comment: Perhaps the key is to make sure the integration test runs before the unit tests...

Comment: Not really, you could if needed force the module to be unloaded. `sys.modules.pop('receivers', None)` would do that.

Comment: As it happens, Django runs integration style tests before unit tests (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#order-in-which-tests-are-executed).  This solves it, thank you!  I'll write up how I did it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One (somewhat imperfect) way of doing it is to use the following TestCase:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class ReceiverConnectionTestCase(TestCase):
    """TestCase that allows asserting that a given receiver is connected
    to a signal.

    Important: this will work correctly providing you:
        1. Do not import or patch anything in the module containing the receiver
           in any django.test.TestCase.
        2. Do not import (except in the context of a method) the module
           containing the receiver in any test module.

    This is because as soon as you import/patch, the receiver will be connected
    by your test and will be connected for the entire test suite run.

    If you want to test the behaviour of the receiver, you may do this
    providing it is a unittest.TestCase, and there is no import from the
    receiver module in that test module.

    Usage:

        # myapp/receivers.py
        from django.dispatch import receiver
        from apples.signals import apple_eaten
        from apples.models import Apple

        @receiver(apple_eaten, sender=Apple)
        def my_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            pass


        # tests/integration_tests.py
        from apples.signals import apple_eaten
        from apples.models import Apple

        class TestMyReceiverConnection(ReceiverConnectionTestCase):
            def test_connection(self):
                self.assert_receiver_is_connected(
                    'myapp.receivers.my_receiver',
                    signal=apple_eaten, sender=Apple)

    """
    def assert_receiver_is_connected(self, receiver_string, signal, sender):
        receivers = signal._live_receivers(sender)
        receiver_strings = [
            "{}.{}".format(r.__module__, r.__name__) for r in receivers]
        if receiver_string not in receiver_strings:
            raise AssertionError(
                '{} is not connected to signal.'.format(receiver_string))
```

This works because Django runs `django.test.TestCases` before `unittest.TestCases`.